# Overwrite existing column and extract values to new columns based on different conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, extract

i have this series which contains country,state,city and i would like to extract them accordingly- refer to the output table

| Region |
| --- |
| US* |
| Arizona** |
| Phoenix |
| Mesa |
| California** |
| Los Angeles |
| San Diego |
| Sacramento |
| Florida** |
| Tampa |
| Miami |
| Canada* |
| Central Canada** |
| Montreal |
| London |

my desired output

| Region | State |  | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US* | Arizona** |  | Phoenix |
| US* | Arizona** |  | Mesa |
| US* | California** |  | Los Angeles |
| US* | California** |  | San Diego |
| US* | California** |  | Sacramento |
| US* | Florida** |  | Tampa |
| US* | Florida** |  | Miami |
| Canada* | Central Canada** |  | Montreal |
| Canada* | Central Canada** |  | London |

is this even possible?

I tried some panda operations with isin() but failed miserably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course it's possible:

```
def split_by_country(region_list: pd.Series):
    result = []
    start_idx = None
    for i, region in enumerate(region_list):
        if region.endswith("*") and not region.endswith("**"):
            if start_idx is None:
                start_idx = i
            elif isinstance(start_idx, int):
                result.append(region_list[start_idx: i])
                start_idx = i
    result.append(region_list[start_idx:])
    return result
        
countries = split_by_country(regions_s) 
countries
```

Above code will splits the series/list of regions to list of lists.
Every sublist starts (index 0) with country name.
Then u can do something like that:

```
country_dict = {country[0]: split_by_region(country[1:])
                for country in countries}
```

`split_by_region` is the same as split_by_country by with different condition (`region.endswith("*") and not region.endswith("**")` > `region.endswith("**")`)

and at the end to (belowe code i write without checking, so it may contains some syntax error) :

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["country","subregion","city"])
for i, (country, subregions) in enumerate(country_dict.iteritems()):
    for subregion, city in subregions.iteritems():
        result_df.loc[i] = [country, subregion, city]
```